# python split a string with at least 2 whitespaces

Tags: python, split

I would like to split a string only where there are at least two or more whitespaces.

For example

```
str = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1'
print(str.split())
```

Results:

```
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS', 'Neue', 'Heide', '25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
>>> import re    
>>> text = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1'
>>> re.split(r'\s{2,}', text)
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

Where

- `\s` matches any whitespace character, like  `\t\n\r\f\v` [and more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- `{2,}` is [a repetition](https://regexone.com/lesson/repeating_characters), meaning "2 or more"

Comment: No need to use regex just do `str.split('  ')`. Also mind you using str as variable name is a bad thing because of the built-in str type.

Comment: @Wessie: `text.split('  ')` will produce lots of empty strings because the number of spaces is often greater than 2.

Comment: `str.split(' ')` results in `['10DEUTSCH', '', '', '', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', '', ' Wahn-Heide', ' -1', '', '', '-1']`. Regex is a good way to split on "2 **or more** whitespaces".

Comment: @JohnY absolutely right, I don't know what possessed me to change the answer without a pandas tag being present - nice fix.

Comment: If you are reading the strings from a textfile and you have to ignore line breaks also:
`re.split(r'\s{2,}', text.replace("\n", ""))` might be useful.

Answer (score 11):

As has been pointed out, `str` is not a good name for your string, so using `words` instead:

```
output = [s.strip() for s in words.split('  ') if s]
```

The .split('  ') -- with two spaces -- will give you a list that includes empty strings, and items with trailing/leading whitespace. The list comprehension iterates through that list, keeps any non-blank items (`if s`), and .strip() takes care of any leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: I think you'd also need to throw a `.strip()` in there to prevent `" -1"` (see @Ashwini's solution)

Comment: `map(lambda s: s.strip(), filter(None, words.split()))` can be a faster alternative although not as readable

Answer (score 5):

```
In [30]: strs='10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1'

In [38]: filter(None, strs.split("  "))

Out[38]: ['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', ' Wahn-Heide', ' -1', '-1']

In [32]: map(str.strip, filter(None, strs.split("  ")))

Out[32]: ['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

For python 3, wrap the result of `filter` and `map` with `list` to force iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of:

- mixed tabs and spaces
- blanks at start and/or at end of the string

(originally answering to [Split string at whitespace longer than a single space and tab characters, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050576/split-string-at-whitespace-longer-than-a-single-space-and-tab-characters-python))

I would split with a regular expression: 2 or more blanks, then filter out the empty strings that `re.split` yields:

```
import re

s = '        1. 1. 2.     1 \tNote#EvE\t \t1\t \tE3\t \t  64\t        1. 3. 2. 120 \n'

result = [x for x in re.split("\s{2,}",s) if x]

print(result)
```

prints:

```
['1. 1. 2.', '1', 'Note#EvE', '1', 'E3', '64', '1. 3. 2. 120']
```

this isn't going to preserve leading/trailing spaces but it's close.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight flaw in the [list-comprehension-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12866686/95852) given earlier. If there are trailing spaces in the input, the split *could* produce a last element which consists of a single space (or some number of spaces less than n, where n is the minimum number of spaces to split on), which Python considers True in Boolean contexts. Thus the last element in the output *could* be an unwanted empty string:

```py
>>> s = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1   '
>>> [t.strip() for t in s.split('  ') if t]
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1', '']
```

There are several ways to fix this. One is to strip each element returned by the split *before* checking its truthiness:

```py
>>> s = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1   '
>>> [t.strip() for t in s.split('  ') if t.strip()]
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

But it seems a bit ugly to strip each token twice. So another way is to strip the input just once at the beginning:

```py
>>> s = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1   '
>>> [t.strip() for t in s.strip().split('  ') if t]
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

That should be good enough if you want to go with a list comprehension. But if you are unhealthily obsessed with [preciseness](https://www.writingtips.cc/precision-vs-preciseness/), maybe you will notice that because splitting happens left-to-right, each of the tokens resulting from the split can only have *leading* spaces, and the unwanted empty string can only happen at the *end* of the final output. Thus, if it is worth the extra two characters to you, you could go with

```py
>>> s = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1   '
>>> [t.lstrip() for t in s.rstrip().split('  ') if t]
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```

If you are using Python 3.8+, you can use the walrus operator to avoid redundant stripping:

```py
>>> s = '10DEUTSCH        GGS Neue Heide 25-27     Wahn-Heide   -1      -1   '
>>> [w for t in s.split('  ') if (w := t.strip())]
['10DEUTSCH', 'GGS Neue Heide 25-27', 'Wahn-Heide', '-1', '-1']
```