# How to split strings in Python based on multiple spaces

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following string:

```
" FROM /TO        FLIGHT  CL DATE   DEP      FARE BASIS    NVB   NVA   BAG  ST    "
```

I wish to split and get the following:

```
FROM /TO

FLIGHT

CL DATE

DEP

FARE BASIS
```

I wish to split the string if the number of spaces between words is 2 or more. How can this be achieved?

```
string.split('  ')
```

did not yield correct results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python split a string with at least 2 whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866631/python-split-a-string-with-at-least-2-whitespaces)

Comment: I don't know if SO strips repeated white spaces or something, but I (and my hex editor) only see single spaces in your string.

Comment: Is your given query contains 2space in between of any two words? If it contains than answer is `str.split("  ")` .

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re` as such:

```
import re    
text = " FROM /TO FLIGHT CL DATE DEP FARE BASIS NVB NVA BAG ST "
text_split = re.split(r'\s{2,}', text)
print(text_split)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your string is NOT separated by two spaces.

This will work

```
print " FROM /TO  FLIGHT  CL DATE DEP  FARE BASIS  NVB  NVA  BAG  ST ".split("  ");
```