# split string using at least n number of white spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I have the following data, which I cannot change:

```
data = """
-5,-2   -52.565           
-5,-1   -48.751           
-5, 0   -47.498           
-5, 1   -48.751          - 
-5, 2   -52.565          
"""
```

I would like to get the columns into two lists, i.e:

```
list1 = ['-5,-2','-5,-1','-5, 0','-5, 1','-5, 2']
list2 = ['-52.565,'-48.751','-47.498','-48.751','-52.565']
```

For now, I am interested to split each line correctly:

```
lines = [l for l in s.splitlines()]

print(lines[2].split())
print(lines[3].split())
```

> ['-5,-1', '-48.751']
>
> ['-5,', '0', '-47.498]

You can see that line[3] was not split correctly, because there is a space between '-5,' and  '0'. To solve this, I have tried the following (based on [python split a string with at least 2 whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866631/python-split-a-string-with-at-least-2-whitespaces)):

```
import re
print(re.split(r'\s{2,}', lines[3]))
```

Success for the first column entry '-5, 0' but it also adds an empty list entry at the end:

> ['-5, 0', '-47.498', '']

How can I solve this  ? Maybe there is a better way to split ?

**EDIT:**

If I use

```
print(re.split(r'\s{2,}', lines[3],  maxsplit = 1))
```

I get:

> `['-5, 0', '-47.498           ']`

Comment: [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) takes an additional parameter **maxsplit** - set it to 1 and you will always split into two columns. I suggest then running [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove trailing whitespaces

Comment: @Arthur.V ahh, this is what I was going to ask you. okay, will try it. :)

Comment: You have spaces after second number, that's why you have empty string. You can use `.strip()` to remove spaces before and after numbers.

Comment: @mx0 True, but I cannot change the data, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Just keep the first two items of the list you get with `re.split`...

Comment: @henry just change `print(re.split(r'\s{2,}', lines[3].strip()))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re` to split lines into columns, then use `zip` function to split columns into two groups:

```py
import re
data = """
-5,-2   -52.565           
-5,-1   -48.751           
-5, 0   -47.498           
-5, 1   -48.751          - 
-5, 2   -52.565          
"""
columns = [re.split('\s{2,}', line.strip()) for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip()]
print(columns)
first, second = map(list, zip(*columns))
print(first)
print(second)
```

output:

```
[['-5,-2', '-52.565'], ['-5,-1', '-48.751'], ['-5, 0', '-47.498'], ['-5, 1', '-48.751', '-'], ['-5, 2', '-52.565']]
['-5,-2', '-5,-1', '-5, 0', '-5, 1', '-5, 2']
['-52.565', '-48.751', '-47.498', '-48.751', '-52.565']
```

Answer (score 1):

try to strip the lines before splitting:

```
print(re.split(r'\s{2,}', lines[3].strip(),  maxsplit = 1)) 
#or 
print(re.split(r'\s{2,}', lines[3].strip()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data = """
    -5,-2   -52.565           
    -5,-1   -48.751           
    -5, 0   -47.498           
    -5, 1   -48.751          - 
    -5, 2   -52.565          
"""
lines = [l.strip() for l in data.splitlines()]
list1 = []
list2 = []
for line in lines:
    if not line:
        continue
    columns = line.split(' '*3)
    list1.append(columns[0])
    list2.append(columns[1])
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it non-regex, overly complicated, and much more verbose you could do this:

```
data = """
-5,-2   -52.565           
-5,-1   -48.751           
-5, 0   -47.498           
-5, 1   -48.751          - 
-5, 2   -52.565          
"""

jumbled_fields = data.split("\n")

divided = list()
for n in range(len(jumbled_fields)):
    for split_field in jumbled_fields[n].split("   "):
        if split_field != "" and split_field[0] != " ":
            divided.append(split_field)

first = list()
second = list()
for n in range(len(divided)):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        first.append(divided[n])
    else:
        second.append(divided[n])
print(first)  # ['-5,-2', '-5,-1', '-5, 0', '-5, 1', '-5, 2']
print(second)  # ['-52.565', '-48.751', '-47.498', '-48.751', '-52.565']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

data = """
-5,-2   -52.565           
-5,-1   -48.751           
-5, 0   -47.498           
-5, 1   -48.751          - 
-5, 2   -52.565          
"""

patternA = re.compile('(-\d+,[\s|-]\d+)')
matches = re.findall(patternA, data)
listA = []

for elem in matches:
    listA.append(elem)


patternB = re.compile('\s(-\d+\.\d+)')
matches = re.findall(patternB, data)
listB = []

for elem in matches:
    listB.append(elem)

print(listA)
print(listB)
```

Explanation of regex (sorry for odd formatting I’m trying to type this up on a phone)

```
In re.compile:
\d+   -   Number with one or more digits
\s     -   Matches single whitespace
[\s|-]  -  Matches whitespace or -
( )      -  Captures group, this part is returned by the findall
```