# line split - how can I retain columns with missing values

Tags: python

I am processing a form output where all fields are not mandatory to be filled. I am reading the values into a dictionary, splitting it and then doing some processing. However, I am finding that when there are values missing then entire column is dropped. So in the example below, since this record has missing data for EndMonth, EndDay, EndYear - these three columns are dropped from the output even though other records have data for it.

```
FirstName       Oliver
LastName        Twist
PhoneNumber     8111456789
EmailAddress    xjk@py.com
StartMonth       2
StartDay 3
StartYear        2020
EndMonth
EndDay
EndYear
```

My code goes something like this....how can I replace the missing value with something like 'blank' or 'NA' to ensure no records get dropped. I am sure this is an easy one but I am a python newbie and so struggling with it

```py
file=open("ztest.txt", "r")
dict_vals={}
for line in file:
    if line.rstrip():
        split_line=line.split()
.....
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the length of `split_line`; if it is less than two append your *placeholder*. `StartDay 3` will be a problem though - you probably want to split on *more-than-one-space*.

Comment: Thank  you . I will give it a shot

Comment: [python split a string with at least 2 whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866631/python-split-a-string-with-at-least-2-whitespaces)

Comment: I believe `StartDay 3` is meant to be interpreted as the line above it; `StartDay` is the key and `3` the value. OP may correct me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no value associated with the key, `line.split()` will only have length 1:

```py
'FirstName       Oliver'.split()  # ['FirstName', 'Oliver']
'EndDay    '.split()  # ['EndDay']
```

So the logic could go like:

```py
split_line=line.split()
if len(split_line) == 1:
    split_line.append('NA')
```

Other possible improvement: define the character to split on explicitely, it may avoid bugs later on. In your case, `' '` or `'\t'` should do.

Comment: All - thank you very much. The solution works beautifully. Now on to another issue. I am trying to load the output into an Oracle table. installed cx_Oracle but getting an oracle library not found error. Figuring that out