# Split string at whitespace longer than a single space and tab characters, Python

Tags: python, string, split, tabs, space

I want to convert `'        1. 1. 2.     1 \tNote#EvE\t \t1\t \tE3\t \t  64\t        1. 3. 2. 120 \n'`, and strings like it, to `['1. 1. 2. ','1','Note#EvE','1','E3','64','1. 3. 2. 120']`. How can this be done?