# How to create a list of list from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **df** and I want to convert the dataframe to a list of list

```
    left_side                                  right_side                             similarity
0114600043776001 loan payment receipt         0421209017073500 loan payment receipt     0.689008
0114600043776001 loan payment receipt         0421209017073500 loan payment receipt     0.689008
vat onverve*issuance fee*506108               vat onverve*issuance fee*5061087       0.743522
vat onverve*issuance fee*506108               verve*issuance fee*506108*********1112    0.684342
verve*issuance fee*506108                     verve*issuance fee*506108*********8296    0.717817
verve*issuance fee*506108                     vat onverve*issuance fee*506108**         0.684342

maint fee recovery jun 2018                   vat maint fee recovery jun 2018          0.896607
maint fee recovery jun 2018                  vat maint fee recovery jun 2018         0.896607
maint fee recovery jun 2018                  vat maint fee recovery jun 2018         0.896607
```

Expected output should look like this:

```
[[0114600043776001 loan payment receipt, 0421209017073500 loan payment receipt,
  0421209017073500 loan payment receipt],
[vat onverve*issuance fee*506108, vat onverve*issuance fee*5061087, 
  verve*issuance fee*506108*********1112], 
[verve*issuance fee*506108*********8296, verve*issuance fee*506108                    
 vat onverve*issuance fee*506108** ],...]
```

I have tried grouping the above df by `left_side column` and converting the resulting df to a list, but the output is not what I expected. please I need your assistance on this

`grouup_df = df.groupby(['left_side']).right_side.sum().to_frame()`

`grouup_df.values.tolist()`

and the output looks like this:

```
['0421209017073500 loan payment receipt0421209017073500 loan payment receipt0421209017073500 loan payment receipt0421209017073500 loan payment receipt0421209017073500 loan payment receipt0421209017073500 loan payment receipt']
['vat maint fee recovery jun 2018vat maint fee recovery jun 2018vat maint fee recovery jun 2018maint fee recovery jul 2018maint fee recovery oct 2018maint fee recovery jul 2018maint fee recovery jul 2018']
```

Comment: See if this helps out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12866648/4985099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
>>> [[k, *g] for k, g in df.groupby('left_side', sort=False)['right_side']]

[['0114600043776001 loan payment receipt',
  '0421209017073500 loan payment receipt',
  '0421209017073500 loan payment receipt'],
 ['vat onverve*issuance fee*506108',
  'vat onverve*issuance fee*5061087',
  'verve*issuance fee*506108*********1112'],
 ['verve*issuance fee*506108',
  'verve*issuance fee*506108*********8296',
  'vat onverve*issuance fee*506108**'],
 ['maint fee recovery jun 2018',
  'vat maint fee recovery jun 2018',
  'vat maint fee recovery jun 2018',
  'vat maint fee recovery jun 2018']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

dfold = {'left_side': ['string','string','string','string'],
            'right_side': ['string','string','string','string']
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(dfold, columns= ['left_side', 'right_side'])
print(df)
df_list = df.values.tolist()
print(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for the `to_records()` method on a Datagrams.
Try `df.to_records()`, you can find its documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html)

Comment: I think the method `to_records()` creates a list of tuples from the dataframe which difference from the expected output.