# Split Strings based on White spaces, new lines and tab spaces in Python

Tags: python, string

How to split a string based on Split Strings based on White spaces, new lines, and tab spaces and store them in a list in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to split a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string)

Comment: @mac9416 that's for a totally different language (C++)

Comment: @jszakmeister awk, good point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string with unknown number of spaces as separator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309684/split-a-string-with-unknown-number-of-spaces-as-separator-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want here is the `.split()` method on strings

```
>>> s = 'one two\tthree\nfour'
>>> s.split()
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```