# Split and print elements from the list

Tags: python

Using Python version : 2.7.5
OS: Linux

```
Path = ['azure_mico docker_telco /AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV:', 'azure_mico google_telco /AWS Cloud/Test/Blender/Service/QA1:']
```

Actually the Path list is too lengthy, It has more than 200 values, bu just for an example I have provided only two;

I want to split the above list, and add a string before each value, and print the output. The **expected output** should look like below:

```
Cloud: azure_mico , Service: docker_telco , CloudPath: /AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV

Cloud: azure_mico , Service: google_telco , CloudPath: /AWS Cloud/Test/Blender/Service/QA1
```

Comment: What is the splitting criteria? If you need to split on whitespaces, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309684/split-a-string-with-unknown-number-of-spaces-as-separator-in-python

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop and the `str.split()` method should be enough for this.

```
for item in Path:
    split_item = item.split(' ')  # Split each item by spaces
    cloud, service = split_item[0], split_item[1]  # Take the first two
    cloudpath = ' '.join(split_item[2:])           # merge the third and onward back into a single string
    # then, print everything in the desired format. 
    # You could also output this information another way, now that you have it.
    print(f"Cloud: {cloud} , Service: {service} , CloudPath: {cloudpath}\n")
```

Executed, prints the following:

```
Cloud: azure_mico , Service: docker_telco , CloudPath: /AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV:
Cloud: azure_mico , Service: google_telco , CloudPath: /AWS Cloud/Test/Blender/Service/QA1:
```

Comment: print(f"Cloud: {cloud} , Service: {service} , CloudPath: {cloudpath}\n")
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you sure you're using python3? In python2 you might need to instead do `"Cloud: {} , Service: {} , CloudPath: {}\n".format(cloud, service, cloudpath)`, as format strings don't exist

Comment: Yeah correct, I removed "f" and it works find. Thank you.

Comment: Is there anyway we can count unique values for "Cloud" key ? e.g. value of cloud is azure_mico, and it being mentioned twice. and also I would like to print only unique values for cloud key.

Comment: You could make an empty list (e.g. `past_clouds = []`) before starting the loop, and then each iteration of the loop check `if cloud in past_clouds: continue` to skip that iteration. And if you pass that check, add the new value by doing `past_clouds.append(cloud)`. If your question is more complicated, I'd advise submitting a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you. Really appreciated your assistance.