# How do I read in numbers (separated with whitespace) from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm using Python 3, and I have a file in the following form:
`27 4 390 43 68 817 83`

How do I read these numbers in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through each line of the file, extract all numbers out of the line by splitting on whitespace, and then append those numbers to a list.

```
numbers = []

#Open the file
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    #Iterate through each line
    for line in fp:

        numbers.extend( #Append the list of numbers to the result array
            [int(item) #Convert each number to an integer
             for item in line.split() #Split each line of whitespace
             ])

print(numbers)
```

So the output will look like

```
[27, 4, 390, 43, 68, 817, 83]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
firstLine = file.readline()
numbers = firstLine.split() # same as firstLine.split(" ")
# numbers = ["27", "4", "390"...]
```

https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-how-to-split-a-string/

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

[Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

[Split a string with unknown number of spaces as separator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309684/split-a-string-with-unknown-number-of-spaces-as-separator-in-python)

Comment: Your output are not actually a list of  numbers but a list of strings! You are also not closing your file! Also what if the file has multiple lines like the ones OP @Uclydde mentioned ? Also I think it will be beneficial if you explain the code instead of posting links to various sources!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks for the tips. I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: No problem! My suggestion was for you to update your answer to handle those cases if you can